# Why doesn't the pipeline take effect in bash in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here is to count the number of sessions by the same login user.

I could run the direct command if I know the specific user name, such as usera, as the following:

```
who | grep usera | wc -l
```

And if I don't know the current user, I need to user parameter. 
But the following codes don't work:

```
currentuser=`whoami`

sessionnumber=`who | grep "$currentuser" | wc -l`
```

What's the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work just fine. What outcome did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Grep has the `-c` flag so the `wc -l` plus the additional pipe is not needed.

```
who | grep -c -- "$USER"
```

`"$LOGNAME"` is also an option instead of `"$USER"`, which one is bash specific? I don't know, all I know is that they are both on `Linux` and `FreeBSD` system. The `--` is just a habit just `in case` the user starts with a dash grep will not interpret it as an option.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> sessionnumber=`who | grep "$currentuser" | wc -l`
> ```

You are assigning the result of the `who | ...` command to a variable and to see its value you can use `echo $sessionnumber`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are confused about parameters and variables.

What you are trying to get is likely

```
who | grep $(whoami) | wc -l
```

The `$()` is equivalent to the backticks you used.

When you write

```
sessionnumber=``
```

this will run whatever is within the backticks and save the output to a variable. You can then access the variable using the dollar notation:

```
echo "$sessionnumber"
```